# Yii2. Как динамически добавить параметры в url?

Tags: url, yii2, route

Например, текущий урл выглдит так:

```
http://site.com/users?UserSearch[name]=damn&UserSearch[age]=100500
```

Этот урл генерирует стандартная поисковая форма, кот. находится в файле _search

Как брать текущий урл и добавлять динамически параметры? Т.е. у меня есть доп ссылки "Отображать по 10 50 100 и все" на странице. Как сделать ссылку, например, на кнопке 50, чтобы она указывала на

```
http://site.com/users?UserSearch[name]=damn&UserSearch[age]=100500&UserSearch[pageSize]=all
```

Прошу заметить, что текущий адрес - /users, а не /users/index 
Не предлагайте клиентские скрипты типа history.js. Как сделать силами феймворка?

Comment: Вернее на http://site.com/users?UserSearch[name]=damn&UserSearch[age]=100500&UserSearch[pageSize]=50

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Писал по документации, без проверки.

```
private function generateSearchUrl(array $additionalParameters = [])
{
    $parameters = array_merge(
        ['users/index',],
        Yii::$app->request->queryParams,
        $additionalParameters
    );
    return Url::to($parameters);
}
...
public function actionIndex()
{
    $context = array(
        'tenResultsLink' => $this->generateSearchUrl(['UserSearch[pagesize]' => 10]),
        'fiftyResultsLink' => $this->generateSearchUrl(['UserSearch[pagesize]' => 50]),
        'hundredResultsLink' => $this->generateSearchUrl(['UserSearch[pagesize]' => 100]),
        'allResultsLink' => $this->generateSearchUrl(['UserSearch[pagesize]' => 'all']),
    );
    $this->render('index', $context);
}
```

Наверняка поддается дополнительной оптимизации.

Comment: Спасибо за идею. Работает. Одна поправочка. Чтобы мёрджилось, передаю так:
    generateSearchUrl(['UserSearch' => ['pageSize' => 'all']])

Answer (score 0):

Добавляет параметр к текущему адресу:

```php
Url::current(['UserSearch' => ['pageSize'=>'all']]);
```

P.S. Не надо изобретать велосипед ;)